# Actions must be plain Objects in React/Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

the problem I'm running into is `Actions must be plain objects` when passing data through my action creators. Basically I'm trying to capture user input through the click of a button, and **based on what button (view) is clicked** the `event.target.innerHTML` is passed to the action creator `fetchDataAsync(view)` which then performs a GET request via axios and dispatches based on what view was selected.

I'm still new with Redux, though, and I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong here. I've seen an async action performed inside an action creator before...

Component connected with Redux:

```
class ViewSelector extends Component {
  selectView(event) {
    this.props.fetchDataAsync(event.target.innerHTML);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <button onClick={this.selectView.bind(this)}>VIEW ALL</button>
        <button onClick={this.selectView.bind(this)}>VIEW LAST WEEK</button>
        <button onClick={this.selectView.bind(this)}>VIEW LAST MONTH</button>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    view: state.view
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ViewSelector);
```

Action creator for dispatching based on `event.target.innerHTML`:

```
export function fetchDataAsync(view) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchData());

    axios.get(DATA_URL)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(res.data));
      if (view == 'VIEW LAST WEEK') {
        dispatch(lastWeekData(res.data));
      } else if (view == 'VIEW LAST MONTH') {
        dispatch(lastMonthData(res.data));
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch(fetchDataFailure(err));
    });
  };

}
```

Any advice is appreciated. Or if you believe there's a more effective way of capturing that user input and passing it to an action creator...I'd be curious to hear more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install redux-thunk to use async action. And then create your store like this

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const store = createStore(YOURREDUCER, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Comment: Okay so I've implemented redux-thunk, but what if the action creator I'm trying to run with thunk has an argument that needs to be passed? In this case view. What I currently have isn't working: `store.dispatch(fetchDataAsync(view));`

Comment: With redux-thunk implemented you should be able to do async calls. It may be other issues with your code. What's the error message? Have you tried debugging to see if the action is triggered or not?

Comment: Figured it out. I already had a `createStore` in another file and forgot about it. Thanks!

Comment: look also at redux-saga and redux-observable projects. both can be used as substitutes of redux-thunk and IMO give you more flexibility

Comment: Import other things like this - `import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";`

Answer (score 1):

The general idea that you have above is correct. In the React component, you want to isolate the information that is relevant for the async function and call the action-creator with that information. The action creator can make an XHR call, and then dispatch actions accordingly.

(I am assuming that you have middleware installed, otherwise do look at something like `redux-thunk` to get started. The middleware helps connect the dots in this case, making sure async actions and results are dispatched appropriately).

Without knowing too much about the `lastWeekData`, `lastMonthData`, etc, I would only suggest possibly simplifying the 'then' part of the call. If there is any special logic, it conventionally belongs in the reducer.