# Axios callback on GET for React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to display a loading spinner while the axios get request is going on and to do so I believe I need a callback from the request. I call the get request in `componentDidMount()` like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchCloudProperties( () => {
    this.setState( { dim : false } );
  } );
}
```

Where hopefully when the data is retrieved, the dimmer(spinner) will go away based off of that `seState` call. I've have callback's with posts, but have never done one with a get. My get action for the data is:

```
export function fetchCloudProperties( callback ) {
  const VARIABLE_URL = '/cloud/properties';
  const request      = axios.get( `${ROOT_URL}${VARIABLE_URL}` )
    .then( request => {
      return ({
        type    : FETCH_CPS,
        payload : request
      });
    } ).catch( ( error ) => {
      console.log( error );
    } )
}
```

Right now the console is complaining about 'Actions must be plain objects' which I am not sure what that means, but also I have seen it complaining about 'unhandled rejection' so not too sure.

**EDIT:** I have a `createCloudProperty` method that uses a callback and it works fine:

```
export function createCloudProperty( values, callback ) {
  const VARIABLE_URL = '/cloud/property';
  const request      = axios.post( `${ROOT_URL}${VARIABLE_URL}`, values )
    .then( () => callback() );

  return ({
    type    : CREATE_CP,
    payload : request
  });
}
```

that is called from:

```
onSubmit( values ) {
  this.props.createCloudProperty( values, () => {
    this.props.history.push( '/cloudproperties' );
  } );
}
```

Comment: Are you using redux, or flux, or something else? Is `fetchCloudProperties` an action creator? If you're doing async actions you need to use something like `redux-thunk` to be able to return promises from an action creator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Actions must be plain Objects in React/Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693161/actions-must-be-plain-objects-in-react-redux)

Comment: @AndyRay I am using `redux-promise`, and yes `fetchCloudProperties()` is an action creator as far as my understanding goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass the request/response because it's not a plain object. You should use the response data.

```
export function fetchCloudProperties( callback ) {
  const VARIABLE_URL = '/cloud/properties';
  const request      = axios.get( `${ROOT_URL}${VARIABLE_URL}` )
    .then( response => {
      return ({
        type    : FETCH_CPS,
        payload : response.data
      });
    } ).catch( ( error ) => {
      console.log( error );
    } )
}
```

Comment: That provides the same error as before. I updated my question with how I did it for a post and that works fine.