# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions in redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

Below is the code for my action creator:

```
export function fetchPosts()
  {
    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`);
    return
      {
        type: FETCH_POSTS;
        payload: request

      };
  }
```

Next to type: FETCH_POSTS, if i add , instead of ; i get the error Unexpected token. Is that the syntax for action creators?

Then if i replace , with ; upon compile i get  the error 'Actions must be plain Javascript Objects.

Any idea why?

Comment: you should return an object. objects properties are delimited by `,` not `;` so it should be `type: FETCH_POSTS,`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Actions must be plain Objects in React/Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693161/actions-must-be-plain-objects-in-react-redux)

Answer (score 2):

GibboK's answer has already pointed out the syntax error.

However, I don't think you understand using actions properly. You run:

```
const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`);
```

This is creating a promise. You are currently returning this in an action. Reducers are meant to be deterministic & side effect free, hence why actions should be plain JS objects. You should not be submitting a promise.

Instead, you should be using some relevant middleware, e.g. [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) or something else. You should send an action when the actual promise has resolved.

As a simple contrived example, using `redux-thunk`:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => (dispatch) => {
    // Send action to notify request started. Reducers often want to
    // update the state to record that a request is pending, e.g. for
    // UI purposes.
    dispatch({type: FETCH_POSTS_START});

    // Start request
    request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`)
       .then(res => { 
          // Successfully received posts, submit response data
          dispatch({type: FETCH_POSTS_COMPLETE, payload: res.data})
        })
       .catch(err => { 
          // API call failed, submit error
          dispatch({type: FETCH_POSTS_ERROR, payload: err})
        });
};
```

*Note this code is just an example and not necessarily suitable for use in a production system.*

Answer (score 0):

When you replace `,` with `;` you get an error because, as stated by your error message, an action must return a JavaScript object.

In JavaScript object properties should be separated by `,` as:

```
return
      {
        type: FETCH_POSTS, // use comma here
        payload: request   
      };
```

In this way the `return` statement will return a new object with two properties `type` and `payload`.

Answer (score 0):

As per **[redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html)** documentation:

> `Actions` are plain JavaScript objects. Actions must have a `type
>   property` that indicates the type of action being performed. Types
>   should typically be defined as `string constants`. Once your app is
>   large enough, you may want to move them into a separate module.

And Action Creators

> Action creators are functions that create actions
>
> In Redux action creators simply return an action:
>
> ```
> function addTodo(text) {
>   return {
>     type: ADD_TODO,
>     text
>   }
> }
> ```

So when you call the `action creator` from your component through `dispatch` your action creator just needs to simply return a plain javascript object.

So a normal action creator will be

```
export function fetchPosts()
  {

    return
      {
        type: FETCH_POSTS;
        payload: "somevalue"

      };
  }
```

Now if you want to call APIs within your action creators you need to make use of middlewares like `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` while creating a store

like

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const store  = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

You you configure your store with middleware you can modify your actions to

```
export function fetchPosts() {
    return (dispatch) =>  {   
        axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`)
               .then((response)=> {
                     dispatch( {
                           type: FETCH_POSTS,
                           payload: request

                     })
                })  
        } 

     }
```

As per the **[redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)** documentation

> **Why Do you need redux-thunk?**
>
> `Redux Thunk middleware` allows you to write action creators that
>   return a function instead of an action. The thunk can be used to delay
>   the `dispatch` of an action, or to `dispatch` only if a certain
>   condition is met. The inner function receives the store methods
>   `dispatch and getState` as `parameters`.