# Redux Actions must be plain objects - error with store setup or action config?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Morning all... getting `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` with the following action:

```
export const addHousehold = user => dispatch =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const hasHousehold = await getUsersHouseholdByUserId(user.uid);
    if (hasHousehold) {
      return reject(
        new Error(
          'You have already generated a household. Please complete the setup steps.',
        ),
      );
    }
    return resolve(dispatch(createHousehold(user)));
  });
```

The Promise should be implicitly returned from this function call, shouldn't it? The action is called on click from a component, the call is here:

```
addHousehold() {
        this.props.addHousehold(this.props.user).then(
          () => {
            this.props
              .addOnboardingStages(this.props.user.uid)
              .then(res => {}, err => {});
          },
          err => this.setState({ errors: { generateHouseholdError: err.message } }),
        );
      }
```

This is my store setup, using Redux thunk as middleware.

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  INITIAL_STATE,
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
);
```

UPDATE:
The createHousehold function looks as follows:

```
const createHousehold = user => {
  const { uid } = user;
  const householdId = uniqid.time();

  return Promise.all([
    setHousehold(uid, householdId),
    setUser(uid, householdId),
  ]);
};

const setHousehold = (uid, householdId) => dispatch =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(uid)
    db
      .collection('households')
      .doc(householdId)
      .set(
        {
          users: [uid],
        },
        { merge: true },
      )
      .then(() => {
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(() => reject());
  });

const setUser = (uid, householdId) => dispatch =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(uid)
      .update({
        household: householdId,
      })
      .then(
        () => resolve(dispatch(receiveHousehold(householdId))),
        err => console.error(err),
      );
  });
```

UPDATE 2
Looks like the issue was dispatch wasn't passed in to createHousehold:

```
const createHousehold = user => dispatch => {
  const { uid } = user;
  const householdId = uniqid.time();

  return Promise.all([
    setHousehold(uid, householdId),
    setUser(uid, householdId)(dispatch) // here
  ]);
};
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Please show your `createHousehold` function

Comment: Will update the post.

Comment: You need despatch only objects like: `{ .type: 'ACTION_TYPE', payload: ... }`, not functions. See [reduxThunk docs](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [actions-must-be-plain-javascript-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341206/actions-must-be-plain-javascript-objects/45343435#45343435)

Comment: Thanks @ArtemMirchenko - I can't wok out how to change it to make it do that in this instance.

Comment: @LeMoi, Please check the duplicate that I mentioned in the above link

Comment: Seems to be that dispatch wasn't passed in correctly, see update number 2